# Partially overriding a virtual function

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

I have an abstract class `BakedGood` from which `CupCake` and `Bread` are derived from. In my assignment, I need to include a virtual function `ToString` in my BakedGood class which returns the description of the BakedGood-- here's an example of two possible descriptions:

```
"Chocolate cupcake with vanilla frosting and blue sprinkles ($1.95)"
"Wheat bread ($4.50)"
```

The price part of the string is shared between classes, so that part must be done within the parent class, BakedGoods, but the rest is individual to the type of baked good, so it must be written in the child class. I know how to completely override the function, but not how to partially override it. How do I code this so the shared part of the string is written in BakedGood's ToString function and the rest is written in CupCake's and Bread's ToString function?

Comment: You asked how a method in a derived class can call a method of the same name in its base class.  scohe001's answer shows you how, but dasblinkenlight's answer more cleanly solves your problem because it does a better job of separating three different responsibilities which are; to know the price of an item,  to know the description of the item and, to implement `ToString()`. In dasblinkenlight's solution, the template for `ToString()` exists in only one place.  In the other, the descriptions are intertwined with the `ToString()`, and there's no single place where the string format is defined.

Answer (score 6):

Make a pure virtual member function, say, `description()`, which would produce the initial part of the string, and call it from your `ToString()` override in the abstract class:

```
class BakedGood {
protected:
    virtual string description() const = 0;
public:
    double price() const ...
    string ToString() const {
        ostringstream oss;
        oss << description() << " ($";
        oss.precision(2);
        oss << price() << ")";
        return oss.str();
    }
};

class CupCake : public BakedGood {
protected:
    string description() const override {
        return "Chocolate cupcake with vanilla frosting and blue sprinkles";
    }
};

class Bread : public BakedGood  {
protected:
    string description() const override {
        return "Wheat bread";
    }
};
```

Note: This implementation uses the [*Template Method Design Pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern), an approach that lets you keep the implementation in the abstract base class, while delegating parts of the job to its derived classes.

Comment: I'd also add override keyword to derived methods

Comment: @Yakk Thanks for the edit! I agree, `override` is a good addition. I also added `const` for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

You could implement the function in the base class and print the price. Then you could override it in the children to print the description and then call the base class print. Below is a simple example:

```
class BakedGood {
    private:
        double price;
        ...
    public:
        virtual void print() const {
            std::cout << "($" << price << ')';
        }
        ...
};

class Bread : public BakedGood {
    public:
        void print() const {
            std::cout << "Wheat bread ";
            BakedGood::print();
        }
};

class CupCake: public BakedGood {
    public:
        void print() const {
            std::cout << "Chocolate cupcake ";
            BakedGood::print();
        }
};
```

See it in action here: [ideone](https://ideone.com/sif5MY)